# Using dialogue box

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

I am working on a game. I have used two *progressbar* as a battery on the players. Now I want to simply display a dialogue box when any of the *progressbar* get emptied. For decreasing the battery I have used the logic of counter which get decreased as collision is detected.

```
BattryLevelCPU.setProgress(counter--);
```

Now I want to use dialogue box to display when this `counter==0`
How I would be able to achieve it? I have tried out like

```
if counter==0{
    //tried code of dialogue box
}
```

I haven't got any result except bunch of errors.
Could I do something like this??

```
 If counter==0 {
  showDialog(DIALOG_ALERT);
}`@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
  switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_ALERT:
      Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      builder.setMessage("This ends the activity");
      builder.setCancelable(true);
      builder.setPositiveButton("I agree", new OkOnClickListener());
      builder.setNegativeButton("No, no", new CancelOnClickListener());
      AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
      dialog.show();
  }
  return super.onCreateDialog(id);
}

private final class CancelOnClickListener implements
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancle selected, activity continues",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}

private final class OkOnClickListener implements
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    AlertExampleActivity.this.finish();
  }
} `
```

Comment: Please elaborate on the errors and/or exceptions

Comment: I am beginer. I have edited my question. Please guide me to get out of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a simple dialog box by visiting [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDialogs/article.html)